# Python server-client using UDP not receiving messages

Tags: python, sockets, udp, client-server

So I am trying to make a python program which transfers files from client to server and vice-versa and firstly I am testing a simple case with simple messages from client to server, where client sends a message: "get files" and server will get this message and send back another message. The problem is that the client sends the message, server receives it and sends the response but client doesn't get it.

**server.py**

```
import time

host = 'localhost'
port = 8080
server_address = (host, port)
socket = sk.socket(sk.AF_INET, sk.SOCK_DGRAM)
socket.bind(server_address)

get_files = "get files"

while True:
    print("Waiting for message to receive")
    data, address = socket.recvfrom(4096)
    if data:
        if data.decode() == get_files:
            print("Getting the list of files present")
            time.sleep(1)
            list_files = "List of files"
            send = socket.sendto(list_files.encode(), server_address)
        else:
            break
    else:
        break
```

**client.py**

```
import time

host = 'localhost'
port = 8080
socket = sk.socket(sk.AF_INET, sk.SOCK_DGRAM)
server_address = (host, port)

action = input()

if action == "get files":
    while True:
        print("Sending request to server")
        time.sleep(2)
        send = socket.sendto(action.encode(), server_address)
        print("Request sent. Waiting for response")
        data, server = socket.recvfrom(4096)
        time.sleep(2)
        if data:
            print("List of files present on server:")
            print(data.decode())
```

Comment: The server is sending the response to the server address, not the client address.

Comment: It should send to `address`, not `server_address`.

Comment: Got it, now works thank you. But if I want to transfer files instead of messages, do I need to write a protocol file in order to deal with possibly large files, giving the losses?

Comment: Yes. See the TFTP protocol, for instance.

Comment: @Steve are you required to use UDP only?  (I ask because file transfer is a lot easier to implement reliably and efficiently over TCP than over UDP)

Comment: I know but I have to use UDP over TCP